# How to ensure as_as_tenant scoped by subdomain can reset password with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, acts-as-tenant

I'm using devise and acts_as_tenant gem and it seems the devise controllers don't inherit from ApplicationController (???) so don't have access to set_current_tenant_by_subdomain

When the password reset link is clicked I get no Tenant scoping by subdomain.

So how do you handle this? Is there an easy way to open up the DeviseControllers to ensure 
set_current_tenant_by_subdomain is called?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps to solve this.

1. Customize the Devise views to include the tenant details. You can do it by using `rails generate devise:views` and editing the generated views.
2. Patch `DeviseController` so that it includes `set_current_tenant_by_subdomain`. `DeviseController` is [inherited by the device controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb) (confirmations, registrations, forgot password, etc.)

The patching would look something like this:

```
class DeviseController < Devise.parent_controller.constantize
  set_current_tenant_by_subdomain(:account, :subdomain)
end
```